# Rails multiple exceptions handler with "exceptions_app" per route namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, versioning

is there any solution how to handle Rails exceptions per route namespace with defined direction `config.exceptions_app` ?

I have versioned interface eg `/api/v1`, `/api/v2`. Every namespace uses different JSON/XML/HTML response structure.

Global definition is nice, but i need something more dynamic.

**RESOLVE:**

`config.exceptions_app` takes closure/lambda block. In that block i could create simple `case` statement like this:

```
config.exceptions_app = lambda do |env|
  case env['REQUEST_PATH']
  when %r{^(\/api\/v1)}
    Api::V1::ExceptionsController.action(:show).call(env)
  when %r{^(\/api\/v2)}
    Api::V2::ExceptionsController.action(:show).call(env)
  when %r{^(\/cms\/)}
    Cms::ExceptionsController.action(:show).call(env)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [rescue_from](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#rescue)? It allows you to catch all exceptions (of a given type) inside the controllers and render them how you wish

Comment: Ah, old good rescue_from. I had forgot about it. I will try it. Give response

Comment: I have used exception_app but with regex to different namespaced routes.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could subclass [`ActionDispatch::PublicExceptions`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/public_exceptions.rb) and overwrite the `call` method to use the path information in the `request` object to get more dynamic. If you want to render different static files you'll have to overwrite `render_html` as well and use something more dynamic that just `public_path`.
Can't give a more detailed answer without more input from you.

Comment: ActionDispatch::PublicExceptions looks like something global. My request is i have multiple namespaced parts of application (let say, something like separated apps or interfaces in one monolithic codebase). Eg Admin and then multiple API interfaces. Every interface has own data structures etc. So when is something wrong, in CMS namespace i show custom HTML page. When is API V1 i show json or xml in defined schema, when is API V2, i show another json schema. As Simple Lime wrote, maybe is rescue_from my way.

Comment: I have using ```exceptions_app``` with case statement